# How to get actual line number like assert does?

Tags: c++

I want to write logger class and i wonder if it's possible.
consider:

```
do_something_funny(&my_cat);
LOG::info("just did something funny with his cat");
cout<< LOG::getAllTxt();
```

output:

```
[0.001s][main.cpp:5] - just did something funny with his cat
```

look at `main.cpp:5`. it was logged from 5 line of this file

I should rather use functions in scope, or create singleton object?

Comment: Most compilers/preprocessors define the `__LINE__` identifier.

Comment: I hope _all_ compilers do it, since it's required by the language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The macro [`__LINE__`](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/__LINE__.html) contains the current line number.

Note that in order to use it effectively, you have to access it from a macro. If you just call a logging function, and it accesses `__LINE__`, it will report the line number within the logging function. So you might define:

```
#define LOGINFO(message) (LOG::info((message), __LINE__))
```

Comment: Also note the `__FILE__` compiler symbol, which contains the source file name.